# Uint8Array input was not valid

Tags: c#, arrays, angularjs, controller, byte

I'm using angular app with .net core backend.

What I want to do, is to do a simple file upload app.

To c# controller I'm sending this json:

```
{"name":"test","extension":".txt","dateCreated":"2017-12-11T10:59:19.156Z","dateModified":"2017-12-11T10:59:19.156Z","data":{"0":89,"1":13,"2":10,"3":49,"4":48,"5":48,"6":13,"7":10,"8":69,"9":13,"10":10,"11":89,"12":13,"13":10,"14":53,"15":48,"16":13,"17":10,"18":72}}
```

It is formed by this TS class

```
export class File {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    data: Uint8Array;
    dateCreated: Date;
    dateModified: Date;
    extension: string;
}
```

Controller looks like

```
// POST: api/Test/Files
[HttpPost("[action]")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Files([FromBody] Files file)
```

And my **Files** class looks like

```
public partial class Files
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public byte[] data { get; set; }
    public DateTime dateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime dateModified { get; set; }
    public string extension { get; set; }
}
```

Response I'm getting:

```
{
  "data.0": [
    "The input was not valid."
  ]
}
```

I think the problem is that my controller can't convert from **Uint8Array** to **byte[]**, but I cant seem to find the solution.

Comment: If you remove `data` (from the JS and the C#) does the problem persist?

Comment: no, the problem does not exist anymore

Comment: @EricLease I think C# (.net core to be exact) doesn't have Uint8Array type. In other question i found out that  byte type in c# is equal to Uint8, so I assumed that Uint8Array would be the same as byte[]. But something is not quite right here

Comment: @mjwills no idea how I missed that one. Trying the fix now, will update if it worked or not.